# How to initialize an interface for viewmodel in a @Preview @Composable

Tags: android, viewmodel, composable

my problem lies with how to initialize an interface in a viewmodel that is to be used in a @Preview @Composable function.  My preview is not showing up in Android Studio because of the following stack trace nor is my next activity (Composables) when I run in emulator or device.

https://1drv.ms/w/s!AnsFOFM6YEPJqKYPTlOnwwfwZ1NNAQ?e=QieFPV

The following codes shows the problem area:

```
@Composable
fun WishListViewModelData(fbVM: FirebaseWishListViewModel) {
val fb = Firebase
val loggedInCurrentUserEmail = fb.auth.currentUser?.email.toString()
val loggedInEmail: String = loggedInCurrentUserEmail
val recipState: State<RecipientData> = fbVM.uiRecipientState.collectAsState()
val purchaserState: State<PurchaserData> = fbVM.uiPurchaserState.collectAsState()
RecipientWishList(
    loggedInEmail = loggedInEmail,
    recipState = recipState,
    purchaserState = purchaserState,
    fbVM = fbVM
)

}

@Preview(showBackground = true, apiLevel = 33)
@Composable
fun WishListBody() {
lateinit var contactsRepository: ContactsRepository
val repoContacts = contactsRepository
val viewModel = FirebaseWishListViewModel(repoContacts)
WishListViewModelData(fbVM = viewModel)
}

@SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
@OptIn(ExperimentalGlideComposeApi::class)
@Composable
fun RecipientWishList(
loggedInEmail: String?,
recipState: State<RecipientData>,
purchaserState: State<PurchaserData>,
fbVM: FirebaseWishListViewModel
) {

val requestManager = Glide.with(LocalContext.current)
val imageFileName: String? = null
val showDialog = remember {mutableStateOf(false)}

var selectedRecipientProfile: MutableMap<String,Any> = mutableMapOf()
val purchaserInfo = purchaserState.value
val purchaserImages = purchaserState.value.purchaserImage?.value!!

Box(
    Modifier
        .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
)
{
   Column (
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(1f)
            .fillMaxHeight(1f)

    )
    {
       // Purchaser Icon Button
        Button(
            onClick = { showDialog.value = true },
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
        ) {
            if (showDialog.value) {

                ShowPopUp(purchaserImages = purchaserImages, fbVM = fbVM)
            }
        }
        // Active recipient picture with gift items
    Row (modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)){
        val recipList = fbVM.getAllRecipientsInfo(loggedInEmail)

        SetRecipientImage(recipientMap = recipList, rm = requestManager, imageURL = 
        recipState.value.recipientImage.toString() )
        val productMap: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
        GetListItems(products = productMap)
    }
        //List of all recipients that belongs to signed in user

    LazyRow(state = rememberLazyListState()){

        val numRecipients = fbVM.getAllRecipientsInfo(loggedInEmail.toString()).count()
        items(numRecipients) {
            ElevatedButton(onClick = {
                selectedRecipientProfile =
                    loggedInEmail?.let { it1 -> switchRecipientProfile(it1, 
   fbVM.getAllRecipientsInfo(loggedInEmail)) }!!
            }) {
                GlideImage(model = recipState.value.recipientImage!!, 
     contentDescription = "${recipState.value.recipientFirstName}"
                    .plus("")
                    .plus("${recipState.value.recipientLastName}")
                )
                Text (recipState.value.recipientFirstName.toString())
                Text (recipState.value.recipientLastName.toString())
                Text (recipState.value.recipientAddress.toString())
                Text (recipState.value.recipientCity.toString())
                Text (recipState.value.recipientState.toString())
                Text (recipState.value.recipientZipCode.toString())
                Text (recipState.value.recipientPhone.toString())
                Text (recipState.value.recipientEmail.toString())

            }

        }

    }


   }

}
}

My view model looks like the following:


package com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.data.viewmodels

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.google.firebase.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.auth.auth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.firestore.firestore
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.tritongames.shoppingwishlist.data.repository.contacts.ContactsRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.getAndUpdate
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.File
import javax.inject.Inject

data class PurchaserData(
val purchaserImage: MutableState<MutableMap<String, String>>? = null,
val purchaserFirstName: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val purchaserLastName: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val purchaserAddress: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val purchaserCity: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val purchaserState: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val purchaserZipCode: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val purchaserEmail: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val purchaserPhone: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val purchaserPassword: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val purchaserUserName: MutableState<String?>? = null,
)
data class RecipientData(
val recipientImage: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientFirstName: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientLastName: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientAddress: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientCity: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientState: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientZipCode: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientEmail: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientPhone: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientPassword: MutableState<String?>? = null,
val recipientUserName: MutableState<String?>? = null,
 )

  @HiltViewModel
  class FirebaseWishListViewModel @Inject
```

constructor(private val contactsRepository:
ContactsRepository) : ViewModel() {

```
  fun repoContacts(): ContactsRepository 
   {
   return contactsRepository
  }

  private val _uiPurchaserState = MutableStateFlow(PurchaserData())
  val uiPurchaserState: StateFlow<PurchaserData> = _uiPurchaserState.asStateFlow()

  private val _uiRecipientState = MutableStateFlow(RecipientData())
  val uiRecipientState: StateFlow<RecipientData> = _uiRecipientState.asStateFlow()

  companion object {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    class FirebaseWishListViewModelFactory(private val contactsRepository: 
  ContactsRepository):
        ViewModelProvider.Factory {

        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T =
            with(modelClass){

                lateinit var vm: T
                when{
                    isAssignableFrom(FirebaseWishListViewModel::class.java) -> 
 FirebaseWishListViewModel(contactsRepository)

                    else -> { throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class: 
 ${modelClass.name}")}
                }


            } as T

    }
}



fun getAllPurchaserPictures(loggedInEmail: String): MutableMap<String,String> {
    val purchaserImagesMap: MutableMap<String,String> = mutableMapOf()
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val purchPictures = _uiPurchaserState.getAndUpdate {
            val pics =
```

mutableStateOf(contactsRepository.getPurchaserPictures(loggedInEmail))
PurchaserData(pics)
}
purchPictures.purchaserImage?.value?.let { purchaserImagesMap.putAll(it) }

```
    }
    return purchaserImagesMap
}
```

// ContactsRepositoryImpl.kt

```
  override suspend fun 
   getPurchaserPictures(loggedInEmail: 
  String): 
   MutableMap<String, String> {

    val filePath = StringBuilder()
    filePath.append("purchasers/")
        .append(loggedInEmail)
        .append("/Images")
    val storage: FirebaseStorage = 
FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    var imageFileNames: 
MutableMap<String,String>

   storage.reference.child("purchasers/$loggedIn 
  Email/Images" )
        .listAll()
        .addOnSuccessListener { it ->
            for(item: StorageReference in 
  it.items) {
                val name = item.name
                val path = item.path
                imageFileNames = 
 mutableMapOf(name to path)
                
 Log.d("ContactsRepositoryImpl", 
 imageFileNames.values.toString())
            }


        }


    return imageFileNames
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/previews#best-practices) says android preview has some limitations.

> "Previews are limited when using ViewModel within a composable. The previews system is not capable of constructing all of the parameters passed to a ViewModel, such as repositories, use cases, managers, or similar."

But, you can solve this easy, just make your component decoupled of the ViewModel object.(The documentation show other examples)

Example:

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(viewModel: ProfileViewModel = viewModel()) {
    ProfileScreenContent(
        name = viewModel.name,
        onNameChanged = viewModel::onNameChanged
    )
}

@Composable
fun ProfileScreenContent(name: String, onNameChanged: (name: String) -> Unit) {
    //TODO ...view...
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun ProfileScreenContentPreview() { // And here you can mock whatever you want
    ProfileScreenContent(
        name = "Test",
        onNameChanged = {})
}
```

Comment: Hey @Paulo, thanks for the help.  It got rid of that problem, and unfortunately generated another problem.  It now complains "Failed to instantiate Composition Local".  Now I read that composition local should be used sparingly.

Comment: No problem, if you would like more help feel free to share more details.

Comment: Hey @Paulo, there is one more question though.  This line of code in  my getAllPurchaserPictures() function is showing null ( mutableStateOf(contactsRepository.getPurchaserPictures(loggedInEmail))).  This is because one variable is not initialized in getPurchaserPictures() function.

Comment: I've updated the code above with getPurchaserPictures() method from my contactsRepository file.  For some reason, the variable imageFileNames is unitialized by Android Studio.  If imageFileNames is not initialized, then I can't return that value.  The way that I tried to initialize imageFileNames should be correct, but it's showing an error.  The only thing is that I could think of it that you can't really return a value when working with Firebase.  You have to write all assignments of variables within .addOnSuccessListener() correct?

Comment: @user1867845 , If I undestand corrent what you want to do,  when you use the preview, the Android will not make any request, you need to mock the responses to use. For exemplo, you need a RecipientData, you just need pass a mock data to the view to use. In another way, if i'm wrong, create a new question with more details what you want, and I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: I was trying to pull in Firebase data into a view model, and then load those functions from view model into Jetpack Compose functions.  A specific example of what I'm trying to accomplish is that I have three images that are stored in a directory in Firebase Storage (/purchasers/{email}/images/) called (1) Katana.jpg, (2) nunchucks.jpg, and (3) rifle.jpg.  The function getPurchaserPictures() that is in my view model pulls those three images in as a MutableList<String,String>.  In my activity, I have a composable function that calls getPurchaserPictures() and displays each as buttons.

Comment: I'm under the impression that I could do this for composable functions that belong in setContent{} under OnCreate() as well as @Preview composable functions.

Comment: If I iundestand what you want, you can't make request for use in the compose, neither using  setContent{} under OnCreate() . You need mock this data localy for use in the preview.